# Flutter google login with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

getCredential is gives error, earlier this code work perfectly.

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<void> signWithGoogle() async {
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
  AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider().getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);

  FirebaseAuth user =
      (await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential)).user;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code (as text not an image), and your error (also as text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

has changed the nomenclature, try changing the 'GetCredential()' to just 'credential', like this:

```
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);
```